# SharePoint 2013 how to get the correct ProfileManager on a farm with two Profile servcie applications

Tags: user-profile-service, userprofilemanager

Here is my situation,  I have a farm that has two profile service applications.  One is a standard user profile service application,  the other is a replicated profile service application. They each run on different servers.

The standard commands for PowerShell to grab and interact with the profile application is as follows:

```
$site = get-spsite https:/siteurl

$context = Get-SpserviceContext $site

$profilemanager = New-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)
```

Then to check if which profile Service the manager is connected to I just have it output the profile count

```
$profilemanager.count
```

The result is always around 40,000   which means it is connected to the my replicated profile service.

I want to connect to the normal profile service so I can interact with profiles programmatically.

Anyone have any ideas how I can connect to either profile service via powershell?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the default application association. Go to Central Admin -->ApplicationManagment --> Configure service Application Association. There you can update which service application your web app is using .